# run fails with INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY

Tags: android, calabash-android

I'm new using calabash to test Android applications.

I implemented some tests to validate an apk implemented with Android Studio 3.0.1 and Gradle version 2.3.3 and that works fine.
The problem appears when i try to execute the tests to validate a new app created with Gradle version 3.0.1 and Kotlin (same AS). Executing the command:

```
bundle exec calabash-android run app-release.apk
```

i'm getting this:

```
adb: failed to install /Users/sonia/Documents/calabash-test-android/app-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]
  Scenario: As a valid user I can log into my app #features/my_first.feature:3
  undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  ./features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb:18:in `Before'
  Will not start test server because of previous failures. (RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in `Before'
    When I press "Login"                          # calabash-android-0.9.2/lib/calabash-android/steps/press_button_steps.rb:17
    Then I see "Welcome to coolest app ever"      # calabash-android-0.9.2/lib/calabash-android/steps/assert_steps.rb:5

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:3 # Scenario: As a valid user I can log into my app

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (2 skipped)
0m4.553s
```

All the other settings defined in AS in the new app are the same as the old app.

Someone knows if there is a problem with the Gradle version?

Answer (score 19):

The [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html) say this

> Note: The Run  button builds an APK with testOnly="true", which means the APK can only be installed via adb (which Android Studio uses). If you want a debuggable APK that people can install without adb, select your debug variant and click Build > Build APK(s).

Even I force to adding  below line to application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:testOnly="false"
```

The Android Studio Run button overrides my setting of it.

I find a working method to stop Android Studio from injecting the testOnly property to application tag.

Add the below line:

```
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

to  gradle.properties gradle config file in your project.

Comment: Life savior! I was stuck with this bug for 2 days. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you a lot @Tshunglee. I was busy to resolve this issue for several hours.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem and tried with `android.injected.testOnly=false` also in manifest `android:testOnly="false"`. But it does not work.

So simple solution which work for me is-  Click on Build option and select Build APK(s). click on locate apk on dialog which appears on right bottom . It will locate your unsigned debug APK .

Answer (score 1):

Just did:

1. Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APKs -> Build APKs
2. Navigate to the directory `build/outputs/apk/release`
3. adb install -r your_app.apk

It appears hitting run will still add the flag even if `android:testOnly="false"` is in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the run configuration, change the deploy option from "Default APK" to "APK from app bundle".

Even though not setting the android.injected.testOnly=false and android:testOnly="false", it still working.

Comment: Please, put all your code part inside code block: [examle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193325)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `android:testOnly="true"` to `android:testOnly="false"` in your AndroidManifest.xml. You can also just remove it, should work both way.

Answer (score 0):

If use preview version of SDK, it forces `testOnly` to be TRUE. Only can skip this error by `adb -t`.  That prevents app with preview SDK releasing on end user.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the following line:

```
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

in the `gradle.properties` file which is located

in `[ROOT_PROJECT]/app/gradle.properties` (or you main app gradle module) and NOT the `[ROOT_PROJECT]/gradle.properties` file.
Otherwise it will not work.